# Unable to find why error "Not enough input arguments", Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I encountered a problem calling the function defined in the code below.. According to Matlab I do not have enough input arguments in the nested function Chi, when I use the function by typing in "Awesomefit(V,I,Ierr)". However I cannot really explain why, since all the input the function needs should be provided.. V, I and Ierr are matrices of 148x1 double and get initialized before calling up the function.

Does anyone have an idea what could be missing?

Matlab also shows an error message in the line with fminsearch. I do not know if this is related to the other error message or to wrongly using the "fminsearch" command. Right now I would think it is the latter possibility. But this is definitely not my main issue. I hope I can cope with that once i got the other problem solved.

Please excuse my unorthodox programming style, but I'm a physicist trying to program :/ I'm still giving my best though..

```
%% do stuff

function a = Awesomefit(V,I,Ierr)

% initialize starting values
A = 1;
Vbd = 25;
n = 1.2;
b = -0.01;
Var = [Vbd n b];

%do stuff
a = fminsearch(Chi,Var);


function Ifit = InotNorm(V,Vbd,n,b)
    Ifit = zeros(size(V));
    for i = 1:length(V)
        if V(i) < Vbd,
            Ifit(i) = 2*10^-12;
        else
            Ifit(i) = A * abs( (V(i)-Vbd) / (V(i)-Vbd+1/(n*b)) )^n;
        end
    end
end


function NM = NormMod(Vbd,n,b)
    NM = sum(InotNorm(V,Vbd,n,b) ./ Ierr);
end


function ND = NormDat(I,Ierr)
    ND = sum(I ./ Ierr);
end


function C = Chi(Vbd,n,b)
    C = sum(( (InotNorm(V,Vbd,n,b) .* NormDat(I,Ierr) ./ NormMod(Vbd,n,b) - I) ./ Ierr ).^2);
end


end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The function you are trying to minimize `Chi` - the input of this function is required to be a **single** variable.  The documentation does specifically say this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html.

   As such, if you have three variables you are trying to minimize, you must put them into a single vector... like you did with `Var`.  As such, you need to change `Chi` to reflect this:

   ```
   function C = Chi(in) %// Change
       Vbd = in(1); %// Change
       n = in(2); %// Change
       b = in(3); %// Change
       C = sum(( (InotNorm(V,Vbd,n,b) .* NormDat(I,Ierr) ./ NormMod(Vbd,n,b) - I) ./ Ierr ).^2);
   end
   ```
2. The first input into `fminsearch` is required to be a **function handle** if you read the documentation carefully.  Therefore, you simply need to change your `fminsearch` call to this:

   ```
   a = fminsearch(@Chi, Var);
   ```

   When you did this before:

   ```
   a = fminsearch(Chi, Var);
   ```

   MATLAB interprets `Chi` as a **variable**, not a function.... which is why you were getting that error.  You need to pass a **handle** to the function as the first input parameter to `fminsearch`.  You can think of a handle as a "pointer" to the function that you are trying to minimize.  Read more about function handles here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html

Doing this and setting `V = I = Ierr = 1`, I get this:

```
>> Awesomefit(1,1,1)

ans =

   25.0000    1.2000   -0.0100
```

Comment: @MSergio - No problem at all.  Good luck!